# Having trouble getting fireEvent working from React-testing-libary

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I have the following code in my unit test which is supposed to make sure that when the user presses enter while focused on an element the website enters full screen mode:

```
  test("TestieMcTestFace", () => {
      const fnFsMock = jest.fn();

      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen = fnFsMock;

      const doSomething = jest.fn();
      renderWithIntl(<Cfdsfdsaaa something ={doSomething} />);

      const element = screen.getByTestId("clickMeToGoFullScreen");
      fireEvent.keyDown(element, {
        key: "Enter",
        code: "Enter",
        keyCode: 13,
        charCode: 13,
      });

      expect(fnFsMock).toBe(1);
    });
```

However, the code that handles keyboards event within the element is never called and the unit test fails with there being no mock calls.

I have tried multiple methods of simulating the keyboard event using react-testing-library but none seem to work. Also, the other unit test which is the same except for using userEvent.click() is passing successfully.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Component Code:

```
<li className="nav-item">
          <span
            data-testid="fullscreenElement"
            className="nav-link"
            onClick={toggleFullScreen}
            onKeyPress={handleEnter}
            tabIndex={0}
          >
            <span className="k-icon k-i-hyperlink-open"></span>
            <span className="d-none d-sm-block">Full screen</span>
          </span>
        </li>
```

Comment: Please provide the minimal, reproducible code of the component

Comment: @slideshowp2 added.